# how remove pdf-toolbar from edge

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

Help me please to show pdf-documents in edge without top pdf-panel  [this pdf-panel which I want to remove is at the picture](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/qGdxUXWadXB_NA). Pdf-documents are opened through hyperlinks. I searched settings and I tried to add "toolbar=0" to my hyperlinks, but without result yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with KJ's comment. The [PDF reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-pdf) is built in in Edge. It's a part of Edge browser so you can't disable the PDF toolbar using code. And there's no setting to disable the toolbar.

You can only open PDF in other applications if you don't want to see the toolbar. Besides, you can also provide your suggestion as a feature request to suggest the Edge team to add a setting to disable the PDF toolbar. You can send the feedback through the [Microsoft Edge Insider](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-edge-insider/ct-p/MicrosoftEdgeInsider) forum.

Comment: K J, Yu Zhou, thank you. I understood, I'll try other viewers for pdf

Comment: Actually this it is possible to avoid toolbar. Just append `#toolbar=0` to the URL, and the toolbar is hidden. I can confirm that the answer from @stefffdev is working.

Answer (score 4):

You can add "#toolbar=0" to the URL and refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F8</kbd> and then Read mode under page view icon, or just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>